# wp_rewrite returning null in plugin settings page

Tags: wordpress, post, plugins, error-handling, url-rewriting

I just wanted to add this as a SOLVED question because it took me a while to figure it out and there was no documentation on this.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-includes/post.php on line 3555

Trying to `wp_update_post(`) via plugin settings page and was getting this notice.

The solution was to add this line before calling the wp function: `$wp_rewrite = new wp_rewrite;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add this line before calling the WP function: `$wp_rewrite = new wp_rewrite;`

Comment: I think the underlying problem might be that you're calling `wp_update_post()` too early. I ran into this problem and solved it by moving the call to a later hook. `$wp_rewrite` gets instantiated fairly early in bootstrap process, though, so there's probably more to it than that.

Comment: @IanDunn Seems to me I can't call that function any later. The function with the wp_update_post() is in a function that fires from a button press and is being called by add_action('init','function')... The fix feels off but I couldn't figure out any other way around it unfortunately.

Comment: I think this answer might help https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75724/fatal-error-get-page-permastruct